# Formatação de valores por páginas Razor

Tags: c#, .net, string, razor, formatação

Estou apresentando problemas na formatação de uma variável através das páginas do Razor no C#.

Digamos que uma variável denominada valor receba o numero 9.5723 (nove reais e 57 centavos), necessito que todas as casas decimais acima de 2 sejam descartadas e a variável se transforme em 9.57 apenas.

Tentei utilizar a seguinte sintaxe

```
string valor = "9.5700"    
string valor = "Custo: R$" + string.Format("{0:F2}", valor).Replace(".", ",");
```

Mas esse `string.Format()` não funcionou. Tentei também utilizar `Split()` na esperança de funcionar mas não é uma método válido. De que forma eu poderia solucionar? Esse `Format()` é valido?

Comment: Tenta `$"Custo: R${valor:C2}"` ou `$"Custo: R${valor:C2}}".ToString(new CultureInfo("pt-BR"))`.

Comment: Utilizando a segunda opção estou tendo o retorno "The type or namespace name 'CultureInfo' is not valid in this scope". utilizei o seguinte codigo para testar, nao sei onde errei string Teste = "9.5744";
"9.5744"
var resultado = "Custo: R${teste:C2}}".ToString(new CultureInfo("pt-BR"));

Comment: O primeiro aparece End of expression expected

Comment: Correção: string Teste = "9.5744";
                 string resultado = "Custo: R$"+ string.Format("{0:C2}",Teste).ToString();

Comment: Provavelmente está digitando algo errado e no outro caso não está inserindo o `namespace` da classe que é a `Globalization`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para formatar valores em Reais no `Razor` faça da seguinte maneira amigo:

```js
@{ 
  var dblNumber = 9.5700;
}

@Html.Raw(dblNumber.ToString("C2"))
```

Saída:

> R$ 9,57

Obs: Se seu valor estiver armazenado realmente em uma string, para esse método acima funcionar terá que substituir o "." por "," e converter para double.

**Mais informações**:
[Standard Numeric Format Strings](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings)

Answer (score 5):

Faça assim:

```
using static System.Console;
using System.Globalization;

public class Program {
    public static void Main() {
        var valor = "9.5789";
        WriteLine($"Custo: R${valor:C2}");
        WriteLine($"Custo: R${valor:C2}".ToString(new CultureInfo("pt-BR")));
        WriteLine(string.Format("Custo: R${0:C2}", valor, new CultureInfo("pt-BR")));
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/xe6uy8). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/jf4QMv). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Decimal/FormatCurrency.cs).

Só acho estranho formatar um valor que já está como `string`, provavelmente isto está errado também.

O segundo só é necessário se a cultura do sistema não é a que você precisa, aí depende do que quer, se é respeitar a cultura do sistema ou garantir que seja a brasileira. A segunda não é tão eficiente então acho que compensa usar o terceiro neste caso.

Estou usando o formatador de valor monetário em vez de formatador de valor científico e estou evitando fazer gambiarra pra trocar ponto que inclusive é ineficiente, além de potencialmente errado.

Comment: po, a questão é que essa é a solução para o Controller, eu necessito de uma solução nas paginas do razor, pois eu não consigo controlar as informações que vem da API dentro dela.

Comment: Agora coloca lá onde precisa. Se você não consegue fazer isto desista. Até porque a pergunta não tem nada de Razor, apenas diz que quer isso, mas não é nosso objetivo fazer por você, ajudamos na solução do problema de acordo com o que foi perguntado, para fazer por você o código Razor que você não fez (pelo menos não postou) não é o que fazemos aqui, isto está errado.